# Trying to write logback output to file

Tags: android, logback

I need to diagnose a problem that some users are having with my app, and want to write debug messages to a log file when they can send to me. I've added the logback and slf4j libaries to my project, and configured an appender in my logback.xml, but I can't find any trace of the output file.

My imports are:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

My logback.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <!-- Create a file appender for a log in the application's data directory -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.FileAppender">
        <file>/data/data/packagename/debug.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Write INFO (and higher-level) messages to the log file -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

and here's where I write logs;

```
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UploadService.class);
...
        if (debugging_on) {
                logger.info("Upload Service Triggered (onCreate)");
        }
```

My code is definitely hitting the logger.info statement, but there's no debug.log file in /data/data/packagename/

Any ideas?

Comment: have you added a write permission?  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Yes I have added that permission but there's no trace of the file.

Comment: I've just run the app again and am getting more info in DDMS. This exception is being thrown: "at ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.android.FileAppender"  ???

Comment: I have the same problem and it seems that it is caused by the fact that the path does not exist.

Comment: Marshmallow (6.0) has a new file permission model (Manifest only is not sufficient any longer).. After catching an OTA update- I too could not access the file system. I verified this by using a downgraded emulator.